# This server accepts the RC4 cipher, which is weak

Tags: ssl, https

I'm using WHM I had installed ssl certificate on my website it's working good but issue is that this tool https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html saying > **This server accepts the RC4 cipher, which is weak**, I'm using apache server WHM with cPanel, Please help me in details, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to stop supporting RC4 ciphers to stop this warning from appearing. https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ has a nice interface where you can plug in your Apache version, choose how flexible you want to be in terms of supporting older client (Modern vs. Intermediate vs. Old), which comes with a security tradeoff, and make the recommended changed to your Apache config file.

The relevant lines are:

> SSLProtocol             xxx
>
> SSLCipherSuite          xxx
>
> SSLHonorCipherOrder     on